# small n: some variables are normally distributed some are not

Tags: nonparametric, paired-comparisons

We performed a biomechanical study, comparing an intact state to 5 different deficiency states on the same knee cadaver specimen. This was conducted on a very small sample size (n=8). My problem is, that some of the 5 deficiency variables are not normally distributed. My original plan was to compare each of the deficiency variable with the intact variable via a paired t-test. As some of the variables are not normally distributed my questions are:

1. Do I have to use a non-parametric test (Wilcoxon) for all variables or only for those,   which are not normally distributed.
2. Can I still use paired t-test, when both variables are normally distributed
3. When I want to apply Bonferroni Correction, do I have to divide the Alpha by the number of total tests performed(parametric and non parametric) or only by the number of  tests performed from the same category.

Comment: I think you'd be hard-pressed to conclude _anything_ is normally distributed from just 8 observations....

Comment: The general problem with these biomechanical studies is, that human cadaver specimen are very rare. Thus, we have to perform a study with such incredibly small sample sizes.

Comment: Yes, we understand you're restricted to small samples. That's fine. The problem @HongOoi was pointing out is that you think you can assert that some samples are from a normal distribution on the basis of only a handful of observations. This is not credible. How did you arrive at this conclusion?